# Make phppgAdmin accessible on Apache/Windows 7

Tags: apache-http-server, postgresql, stack

I have my custom stack folder located here...

> C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAPP\

I have Apache located here...

> C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAPP\Apache 2.4\

I have PostgreSQL located here...

> C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAPP\PostgreSQL 9.3 x64\

...and I have phppgAdmin located here...

> C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAPP\phppgAdmin 5.1\

How do I make phppgAdmin accessible via localhost at the url `localhost/phppgadmin/`?

---

So far I've gone in to `C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAPP\Apache 2.4\conf\httpd.conf` and added `Include conf/extra/phppgadmin.conf` so the file at `C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAPP\Apache 2.4\conf\extra\phppgadmin.conf` is seen by Apache. I've tried numerous iterations including my XAMPP stack's copy of phpmyAdmin code without success. Here is what I currently have in `phppgadmin.conf`...

```
Alias "/phppgadmin/" "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/WAPP/phppgAdmin 5.1/"

<Directory "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/WAPP/phppgAdmin 5.1/">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further research revealed that Apache 2.4 handles things a bit differently...

```
Alias "/phppgadmin/" "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/WAPP/phppgAdmin 5.1/"

<Directory "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/WAPP/phppgAdmin 5.1/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
Require local
</Directory>
```